# winston and loggly nothing shows up on loggly dashboard

Tags: node.js, winston, loggly

Trying to set up loggly with winston, and nothing shows up! I tried a catch-all source group:

[image: loggly source group]

And tried a simple info log:

```
winston = require 'winston'
Loggly = require('winston-loggly').Loggly

winston.add Loggly, {
  subdomain: "my-subdomain",
  inputToken: "my-input-token-ihawof9ahw3fo9ahwe",
  json: true
}

winston.info 'Hello Loggly!'
```

What could be wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Loggly released new version - Gen2. Gen2 is not implemented in winston-loggly package yet. After my communication with Loggly Team I found out a solution based on [this issue comment](https://github.com/nodejitsu/node-loggly/pull/28#issuecomment-26730172):

```
var winston = require('winston');

require('winston-loggly');

var logger = new (winston.Logger)({
    transports: [
      //new (winston.transports.Console)(),
      new (winston.transports.Loggly)({
            inputToken: 'mytoken',
            subdomain: 'mydomain',
            auth: { username: 'myusername', password: 'pswd' },
            json: true
        })
    ]
});

Object.defineProperty(logger.transports.loggly.client.config, 'inputUrl', {
    value: 'https://logs-01.loggly.com/inputs/',
    enumerable: true,
    configurable: true
});

logger.info('Hello Loggly!');
```