# Winston-loggly - How to send a level: 'fatal' message to loggly?

Tags: node.js, winston, loggly

can someone help me ?

Is there a way to send a fatal level message via winston-loggly on nodejs ?

Is there a way to send a 500 status code instead a 'info' string ?

```
const winston  = require('winston');
require('winston-loggly-bulk');

winston.add(winston.transports.Loggly, {
    inputToken: "mytokenhere",
    subdomain: "mysubdomain",
    tags: ["Winston-NodeJS"],
    json:true
});

winston.log('fatal','<i>testing fatal</i>');
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can have `level` field in your options with log level specified. It will then log only those error to loggly.

```
winston.add(winston.transports.Loggly, {
level: 'error'
});
```

You can keep other options as is.

Comment: thanks for the help Sandip.
But nothing happens, even if I add the level: fatal as a option
the log is not send to loggly

Comment: I think there is no level called fatal in winston. try using anythin from following:

{ 
  emerg: 0, 
  alert: 1, 
  crit: 2, 
  error: 3, 
  warning: 4, 
  notice: 5, 
  info: 6, 
  debug: 7
}

Comment: I tried to define these custom levels, but with no success.
I'm using the winston-loggly-bulk package from offical Loggly docs and following the instructions:  https://www.loggly.com/ultimate-guide/node-logging-basics/

the only levels that work are info, error, debug and warn

Comment: I think https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19612060/winston-and-loggly-nothing-shows-up-on-loggly-dashboard?rq=1 will help you.